# Filtering a File Array in Java

Tags: java

How would I filter a File array to only assign pdf files to the array?
Some pseudo code for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
File [] files; //this contains [3] array items

files.filter(pdf); //??

System.out.println("PDF only files:" files);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pdf files end with `.pdf` you can simply filter on the name:

```
List<File> pdfs = new ArrayList<>();
for(File f : files) {
    if(f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
        pdfs.add(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html)

```
File dir = new File("/your/dir");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
    }
});
```

Comment: You could use a lambda for this.

Comment: `File[] files = dir.listFiles((dir, name)-> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"))` (I like one-line solutions)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle this is only Java 8, though

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Apache Commons` you can also use [`SuffixFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/SuffixFileFilter.html)

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles(
    (FileFilter) new SuffixFileFilter(".pdf", IOCase.INSENSITIVE));
```